# Time regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the javascript regular expression for 24H time? Such as:

18:30

I need to assign the regex string to a variable to be used over and over.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

> "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$
```

It will require either a 0 or 1, followed by any digit (00 to 10 hours) or a 2 followed by 0, 1, 2, 3 (20 to 23 hours), an optional colon (take out the `?` to make it required) and then a 0-5 followed by any digit (minutes).